# How to change button font on hover on CSS?

Tags: css, web, fonts, hover

I'm new with CSS.
Is it possible to change the font type of a button when hovering?
I have found a lot of posts considering the change of color, but not the change of font.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make use of [`button:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

```css
button {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

button:hover {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button>Hover on me to change font !</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button font on hover by using the "`:hover`" pseudo-class in CSS.

For example:

`button:hover { font-family: sans-serif; }`

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way if you add font-family: then the font style you want to use to your button:hover it will display the different font when hovered over [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kEPt.png)  [button code in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZkqi.png)[button when hover active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xVGd.png)